# Problema al desactivar y activar inputs

Tags: input, radio

Tengo el siguiente problema: Tengo dos radio buttom (si/no) los cuales al presionarse deben activar o desactivar varios input, el dilema es que únicamente me funciona con el primer input, el resto no cambia, les adjunto codigo:

```js
 function activar(){
    document.getElementById('puesto').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('telefono').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('nomEmpresa').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('direccion').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('fechaIngreso').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('salarioBru').disabled = false;

    return true;


}
function desactivar(){
    document.getElementById('puesto').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('telefono').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('nomEmpresa').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('direccion').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('fechaIngreso').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('salarioBru').disabled = true;
    
    return true;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" name="decision" type="radio" value="si" id="si" onclick=" activar()"/>
    <label class="form-check-label">Si</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" name="decision" type="radio" value="no" id="no" onclick="desactivar()"/>
    <label class="form-check-label">No</label>
</div>

<input placeholder="puesto" id="puesto">
<input placeholder="telefono" id="telefono">
<input placeholder="nomEmpresa" id="nomEmpresa">
<input placeholder="direccion" id="direccion">
<input placeholder="fechaIngreso" id="fechaIngreso">
<input placeholder="salarioBru" id="salarioBru">
```

Comment: en el onclick "return activar()" está demás el return, es solamente onclick="activar()"

Comment: @LPZadkiel, sigo con el mismo problema, solo me desactiva el campo de "puesto" :(

Comment: Para qué retornas valores en esas 2 funciones si en realidad no hace nada eso?

Comment: @javdromero estoy aprendiendo sobre js, por lo que los pensaba necesarios, sin embargo, si los elimino tampoco me desactiva los input que no sean el de "puesto"

Comment: Agrega el html donde están todos esos inputs

Comment: El problema está en que estás usando `document.getElementsById` cuando deberías usar `document.getElementById` (Element va en singular, sin la "S") Por eso funciona solo con el primer input que no tiene la "S". Si ves tu consola cunado intentas ejecutar tu código (Cosa que te recomiendo hacer cada vez que algo no funciona) veras que el mensaje de error dice `Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsById is not a function `

Comment: @AndresGardiol Te lo agradezco enormemente, hermano, ya funcionó

Comment: Genial, si lograste solucionar tu problema te recomiendo que respondas a tu pregunta con la solución. Saludos